# If we Change source code outside Android studio is it work with Android studio

Tags: java

If I change certain assets in a source code file , I mean if I move all needed assets along with json in source code using a file manager and change AD mob id does the source code still works in Android studio without any problem

Comment: isn't testing this faster than posting question on SO? :)

Comment: do you know the answer if so please tell :)

Comment: I suppose it does - Android Studio is just an IDE and I see no reason why should it not work with any proper code no matter what is editing it

Comment: what I mean is to change the entire source code out of Android studio including layout and strings(Ad ids) if I done so is still work in Android studio

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you change the source code of any xml or java file outside the android studio then it will work if it is correct.

Comment: Likewise don't post an answer that isn't an answer. You can flag the question instead.